# Azure (Synpase) Binary == Hex?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I wonder how to get "real" binary dtypes in azure synpase.

If I use the following expression it seems to me that the function returns HEX values (see image) instead of binary type values:

```
toBinary(toInteger(zlm_flags))
```

Since my col of interest is a flag, I actually I want to have the first bit.

[image]

Comment: can you please clarify what UI you are using?  It is showing it to you in that UI as hex, but the data in memory is actually binary.  If you just want a single bit, you can do col & 1 and then you can cast it to a bool which would be cheaper.

Comment: Big thanks! I use the default data-preview functionality within a azure-synapse data-flow item. I solved it within a spark-notebook but netherlesse thaks for the hin. I will try it because of the better performance. One more questions there is a function bin() in spark but I can't see the function in synpase. Is it not implemnted yet or is there a sth else to it?

Comment: In all client drivers for Synapse SQL, selecting a binary column returns it as binary.  So, there is no need for a function to do this as such.  It just so happens the client tool you are using (built on top of a driver) is defaulting to show you things in hex when you query it.  For other types you can CAST to binary to see things in binary (or hex in your tool)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Conor Cunningham MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6724175/conor-cunningham-msft) and [Bohniti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13279582/bohniti) for your valuable discussions. Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> In the UI, the value is shown in HEX values but the data is Binary. To
> obtain single bit, you can do COLUMN & 1 and cast it to bool. This
> would be cheaper.

**There is a function bin() in spark but I can't see the function in synapse. Is it not implemented yet or is there a sth else to it?**

> In all client drivers for Synapse SQL, selecting a binary column returns it as binary. There is no need for a function to do this as such. It seems like client tool that you are using is showing the hex values by default. For other types you can CAST to binary to see things in binary (or hex in your tool)